# Powershell: move files to corresponding folder based on prefix

Tags: powershell, move

I have a bunch of pdf files in my current directory like this

```
PLA_01005_A.pdf
PLA_09003_A.pdf
PLA_11234_B.pdf
PLA_16555_A.pdf
...
PCA_02222_C.pdf
PCA_05555_A.pdf
PCA_06666_A.pdf
...
```

I need to automate the moving of those files into an existing directory structure on another drive like this

```
V:\PLA\PLA_01\
V:\PLA\PLA_02\
...
V:\PLA\PLA_16\

V:\PCA\PCA_01\
V:\PCA\PCA_02\
...
V:\PCA\PCA_06\
```

So the script need to pick the first 3 characters of the file name for the first directory, and the first 5 characters for the sub-dir.

Should overwrite existing files without prompt.

Should leave files at current directory if corresponding target directory does not exist (variant 1) or create corresponding directory (variant 2) and move files.

Something I tried

```
$pla = @(1..17 | % tostring PLA_00*)
#$pla2 = @("PLA\\"+$pla)
$pla2 = @(1..17 | % tostring V:\\_pdf\\PLA\\PLA_00)
$dest = "V:\_pdf\$($dest)"
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.pdf -Filter '$pla' | Move-Item -Force -Verbose -Destination '$pla2'
```

Comment: Cool task description, but you forgot to ask a question. Which part do you need help with, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your initial attempt. What happens when you run the code? Does it throw errors? Does it have unexpected side effects? Nothing happens? Please be mindful that only you can see your screen :)

Comment: $pla and $pla2 arrays get successfully expanded, but the test pdf file I have in current dir does not move in target dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by focusing on a single file, then break down the task into required steps:

- Take the first 3 characters from the file name
- Take the first 6 characters from the file name
- Ensure that a corresponding folder exists
- Move the file

```
$file = Get-Item C:\Path\to\files\PLA_012345_A.pdf

# define the destination path
$destinationPath = "V:\"

# extract the first 3 characters
$prefix1 = $file.Name.Substring(0,3)

# extract the first 6 characters 
$prefix2 = $file.Name.Substring(0,6)

# make sure the folder is created if it doesn't exist already
$prefixFolderPath = Join-Path $destinationPath (Join-Path $prefix1 $prefix2)
if(-not(Test-Path $prefixFolderPath)) {
    New-Item $prefixFolderPath -ItemType Directory |Out-Null
}

# then move the file, `-Force` will ensure existing files are overwritten
$file |Move-Item -Destination $prefixFolderPath -Force -Verbose
```

Now that we've solved it for 1 file, we simply need to loop through *all* the relevant pdf files:

```
# define the destination path
$destinationPath = "V:\"

# discover the files
$pdfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter ???_??*.pdf

foreach ($file in $pdfFiles) {
    # extract the first 3 characters
    $prefix1 = $file.Name.Substring(0,3)

    # extract the first 6 characters 
    $prefix2 = $file.Name.Substring(0,6)

    # make sure the folder is created if it doesn't exist already
    $prefixFolderPath = Join-Path $destinationPath (Join-Path $prefix1 $prefix2)
    if(-not(Test-Path $prefixFolderPath)) {
        New-Item $prefixFolderPath -ItemType Directory |Out-Null
    }

    # then move the file, `-Force` will ensure existing files are overwritten
    $file |Move-Item -Destination $prefixFolderPath -Force -Verbose
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. How about variant 1 / leave files at current directory if corresponding target directory does not exist?

Comment: @JuTutt You can put a `continue` statement inside the `if` block that tests if the folder path doesn't exist (replace the `New-Item ...` statement) - `continue` will cause PowerShell to skip the remainder of the loop body and continue to the next item